# Convert longhand border-radius into shorthand using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to convert

`style="border-top-left-radius: 20px; border-top-right-radius: 20px; border-bottom-right-radius: 20px; border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;"`

into

`style="border-radius: 20px"` (or if the other corners are different corners have different values for it to be `style="border-radius: A#px B#px C#px D#px"`)

I already have the file, and am trying to do the conversion using JS since this would be a regular thing.

I was trying to use something along the lines of

```
document.querySelectorAll('.possible-border-radius').forEach(node => {
...
}
```

but I am unsure how to manipulate the DOM afterwards.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This feels like an XY problem: why is there a need to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do in Vanilla:

```js
// the selector is the class "c"; feel free to change it to anything
document.querySelectorAll(".c").forEach(node => {
  const style = node.getAttribute("style").split(/; ?/g); // get the style of the node and split them into seperate styles
  if (!style[style.length - 1]) style.pop(); // if the style ends with ";" get rid of it
  let remainingStyles = []; // save all non-border-radius styles so we can add them again
  let stack = style
    .map(st => {
      const data = st.split(/: ?/); // get the key and value of the css
      return {
        pos: data[0],
        val: data[1]
      };
    })
    // optional if you are accounting for extra CSS values:
    .filter(st => /^border-(top|bottom)-(left|right)-radius$/.test(st.pos) ? true : (remainingStyles.push(st.pos + ": " + st.val), false));
  const allTheSame = stack.every(v => v.val === stack[0].val); // Array.prototype.every returns true only if looping through the array the callback always returns true
  if (allTheSame)
    node.setAttribute("style", `border-radius: ${stack[0].val}; ` + remainingStyles.join("; ")); // all the same values! use the shorthand
  else {
    let template = "border-top-left-radius border-top-right-radius border-bottom-right-radius border-bottom-left-radius"; // a template for the placement
    stack.forEach(i => {
      template = template.replace(i.pos, i.val); // replace the template data with the template values
    });
    node.setAttribute("style", "border-radius: " + template + "; " + remainingStyles.join("; ")); // set the result
  }

  // for the demo:
  console.log(node);
});
```

```html
<div class="c" style="border-top-left-radius: 20px; border-top-right-radius: 20px; border-bottom-right-radius: 20px; border-bottom-left-radius: 20px; color: hotpink; background-color: blue;"></div>
<div class="c" style="border-top-left-radius: 10px;border-top-right-radius: 20px; border-bottom-right-radius: 30px; border-bottom-left-radius: 50px"></div>
<div style="border-top-left-radius: 20px; border-top-right-radius: 20px; border-bottom-right-radius: 20px; border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;"></div>
```